# Using /etc/hosts or iptables to redirect site to https:// version

Tags: networking, iptables, hosts

I'd like to have my system automatically take me to https://facebook.com even if I put http://facebook.com into my browser.  I can get `/etc/hosts` to redirect to me to different domains, but it seems to ignore it if I put `https://` into it.

This works, and it redirects facebook.com to google.com:

```
74.125.95.103    facebook.com
```

This does not

```
https://74.125.95.103   facebook.com
```

My guess is that you can't use text at all in the part where the IP is, but how do I force it to use https?  Is this possible in `iptables`?

Comment: Since this question was asked, many website such as Facebook now redirect to https by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not possible using `iptables`.

If you used it to redirect port 80 to port 443, your browser would still speak to it using `http` rather than `https`, and all you would get is garbage.

Maybe something using a Squid proxy would work.  You could make it a transparent proxy if you can't change everyone's proxy settings.

Or, if it's just for Facebook, there is a [new per-user setting to force HTTPS](http://www.onlinesocialmedia.net/20110127/facebook-security-addition-of-https-access/) that might work for you when it is rolled out.

Or, if you're using Firefox, check out [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2010/06/encrypt-web-https-everywhere-firefox-extension).

Comment: To further @Mikel's comments about why it wouldn't work:  The browser is speaking HTTP to port 80.  You'd need to somehow convince the browser that it visited a web server that returned a 302 status return, which would redirect the browser to the SSL page.

Comment: If you're using Firefox, you can also install the NoScript addon, which has a setting that allows you to force the use of HTTPS on whatever domains you specify. See http://www.ghacks.net/2010/10/31/how-to-force-https-connections/ for details.